# Is it possible to limit the number of previous users on login screen in centos?

Tags: linux, centos, login, gnome, gdmgreeting

I'd like to customize the login screen on CentOS to limit the number of users displayed? I know how to disable the user's list by customizing the dconf gdm db but I wonder if I can set a limit value...

Comment: Finally ended up not displaying a limited number of users.